# How to open/create images in Python without using external modules

Tags: python, image-processing, pypy

I have a python script which opens an image file (.png or .ppm) using OpenCV, then loads all the RGB values into a multidimensional Python array (or list), performs some pixel by pixel calculations solely on the Python array (OpenCV is not used at all for this stage), then uses the newly created array (containing new RGB values) to write a new image file (.png here) using OpenCV again. Numpy is not used at all in this script. The program works fine.

The question is how to do this without using **any** external libraries, regardless whether they are for image processing or not (e.g. OpenCV, Numpy, Scipy, Pillow etc.). To summarize, I need to use bare bones Python's internal modules to: 1. open image and read the RGB values and 2. write a new image from pre-calculated RGB values. I will use Pypy instead of CPython for this purpose, to speed things up.
Note: I use Windows 10, if that matters.

Comment: Look at the source code of library of the operations you want to perform.

Comment: For more:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-images-python/

Comment: Huh? First you say OpenCV is not used then you say it is used again. Which?

Comment: Do you need to both read and write both `PPM` and `PNG`, or is either good enough?

Comment: OpenCV is not used "for this stage", i.e. for the calculations on the Python array...

Comment: Either is good (I use Gimp to change the file format as I need).

Comment: I don't get it? What's the point of precluding the use of OpenCV when it is required for the other aspects?

Comment: I use OpenCV in the existing CPython script, but I need to switch to Pypy (for speed). But Pypy does not like OpenCV or Numpy (or me), so I want to get rid of OpenCV or other external modules altogether.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a `PPM` file like this without **OpenCV** or **numpy** or anything that hates you :-

```
import array
width,height = 800,600

PPMheader = 'P6\n' +str(width) + ' ' +str(height) + '\n255\n'

# Create and fill a red PPM image
image = array.array('B', [255, 0, 0] * width * height)

# Save as PPM image
with open('result.ppm', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(bytearray(PPMheader, 'ascii'))
   image.tofile(f)
```

[image]

---

I wrote a really simplistic PPM reader too - it only reads 24-bit P6 PPM files matching the ones written above. I guess it could be fleshed out to handle comments, 16-bit data and greyscale data, but it's a start:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import array

def ppmread(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        # Read first line - expecting "P6"
        line = f.readline().decode('latin-1')
        if not line.startswith('P6'):
           print("ERROR: Expected PPM file to start with P6")
           return False

        # Read second line - expecting "width height"
        line = f.readline().decode('latin-1')
        dims = line.split()
        width,height=int(dims[0]),int(dims[1])

        # Read third line - expecting "255"
        line = f.readline().decode('latin-1')
        if not line.startswith('255'):
           print("ERROR: Expected 8-bit PPM with MAXVAL=255")
           return False

        image= f.read(width*height*3)

ppmread('test.ppm')
```

---

Convert PPM to PNG or JPEG with **ImageMagick** in Terminal:

```
convert result.ppm -auto-level image.png
```

Or:

```
convert result.ppm -resize 1024x768 image.jpg
```

Likewise, convert JPEG to PPM with **ImageMagick** in Terminal:

```
convert image.jpg -depth 8 image.ppm
```

Comment: We are getting somewhere now... After I copied-pasted your code I have Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    with open('result.ppm', 'wb') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'result.ppm'

Comment: You need to run in a directory you can write to.

Comment: It worked once I got out of the Shell and opened it as a new file. It's a good start. I still need to figure out how to read RGB values from an image...

Comment: No, read the RGB values of an arbitrary image I already took with a camera. I can convert just about any image to .ppm (using Gimp), if the .ppm format is the easiest to handle in Python (or Pypy) without external libraries..

Comment: PPM is definitely the easiest, as you can see above. It's late here, so I may try and do code to read PPM images tomorrow.

Comment: I don't expect you to write code for me, but pointing me in the right direction (like what Python/Pypy internal modules I should use...) would be of great help. Amin Rigo was teasing with "5 lines of code", but he stopped there...

Comment: Yeah, I took 6 lines 

Answer (score 1):

Working with bare-bones .ppm files is trivial: you have three lines of text (`P6`, "width height", `255`), and then you have the `3*width*height` bytes of RGB.  As long as you don't need more complicated variants of the .ppm format, you can write a loader and a saver in 5 lines of code each.

Comment: Armin, the reason I asked the question is precisely because I could not figure out the '5 lines of code' thing. Can you give me a hint about the main module(s) I should use (is it os by any chance?). It's funny that before I asked the question I watched some of your EuroPython presentations on youtube about Pypy, trying to figure out how to make Pypy recognize all the external libraries, including OpenCV... No success, therefore I decided to eliminate the external libraries from the Pypy code. Thanks.

Comment: @NP1: if you are having problems reading PPM files, post a new question with your code and explain why you cannot get it to work. You might be disappointed to learn that reading a PNG *without any external library* requiries a bit more than 5 lines of code, and is probably way too broad for a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: You don't need any module.  You just open the file (in binary mode), read three lines from it and get the width and height, and then read all the remaining data and get an array of RGB values (as a single bytestring)

Answer (score 1):

Based on various input (kudos to Mark Setchell for his code snippets), now I was able both to read the rgb values, then process them pixel by pixel, then write a new image file, all without using any external libraries. When I started all this I used CPython with OpenCV and Numpy and the runtime was no less than 60 minutes. Then I re-wrote the code without Numpy or OpenCV and ran it using Pypy: it took only two minutes to finish! This is despite the very large size of the ppm file as compared to the original jpg. The write-ppm part was addressed by Mark. He also suggests an automatic way of dealing with variable headers (luxury for me...). This describes my process, showing only the read-ppm part (I am sure it can be cleaned up further):

```
# have image file as png, bmp, jpg etc. and open in GIMP.
# from GIMP, export the image file as myPicture.ppm (use ASCII option, not RAW).
# examine the header of the ppm file to find the exact locations of the width, height and maxvalue. Used Notepad.

# Python code
# BEGIN read the ppm image
h_ind=9; w_ind=8; mval_ind=10 #indexes for height, width, maxval in the ppm header
with open('myPicture.ppm','r') as ppm: # open the ppm file
    data=ppm.read()
values=data.split()
for i in range(mval_ind,len(values)):
    values[i]=int(values[i]) # convert rgb data from string to int for later numeric processing
height=int(values[h_ind]); width=int(values[w_ind]); mval=int(values[mval_ind]) # read height, width, maxvalue
rgb0 = [tuple(values[i:i+3]) for i in range(mval_ind+1, len(values), 3)] # contains all rgb values as integers
# END read the ppm image
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open your image files in the same way you would do for text files. Just adapt to the convention of your .png images.

For PNG look at https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics and read the chunks accordingly